# What is meant by "complete set" in the context of affine wavelets?

Tags: wavelet

In the book by Sayood on compression, he says "if the set is complete, it is called affine wavelets".  I want to know what is meant by completeness of wavelets.

Comment: No, I wanted to say completeness of  a set.

Comment: You can always edit your question, that's better than adding a comment correcting the question.

Comment: Your quote lacks context, so you leave everyone guessing, really. Completeness may refer to a number of concepts, and it could for example mean that the wavelets span the signal space.
Make your question better by giving more relevant context and a pointer to the book.

Comment: Yes,  It is better to edit than correct the question through comments.  I tried that and only when failed I added as a comment.  I could not find edit that time.  Also a while back, when I was trying to include this comment, it was not taking in this comment too.  The box was just appearing and disappearing immediately.

Comment: OK.  This is from  - the very top line - page no. 480  of 3rd edition of Introduction to data compression by Khalid Sayood. " The most popular approach is to select a = a0^(-m) and b = nb0a0^(-m).  If this set is complete then psi_m,n(t) are called affine wavelets."